# What to do when question after some time starts to contain the answer?

Tags: discussion

I didn't know how to express the situation shortly in the title, but the problem I have is:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231369/how-do-you-create-multiple-box-shadow-values-in-less-css/) is not a question anymore, because solution that OP tried (and said it doesn't work) clearly works now. I think it might have changed over time.

I've posted a comment and an answer with full explanation of why OP's approach work, but it seems to get no attention because there are already other (overly complicated as for now) answer with a high number of upvotes.

What else should be done here?

Comment: This is really just another case of you coming up with a better answer to an old question with existing highly upvoted answers, which is a situation discussed often enough already.  Commenting on those answers and providing your own is a very good start, and can be enough in many cases.

Comment: Well the explicitly stated goal of the OP is "I figured I should keep up with what (I think) the best answer is (based on the LESS documentation) as the LESS project matures, and change my accepted answer accordingly." so maybe once they evaluate it they will select it if they agree.

Comment: The OP seems to be online regularly, but he doesn't take any steps towards evaluating my answer. Also, @Servy, this is a bit different case because this question doesn't need answering anymore.

Comment: @MichałRybak Then why did you feel the need to post an answer.  Saying that the code is now working *is an answer*.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9231369/revisions), the question now looks practically identical to the way it did half-an-hour after it was posted (apart from the initial notice) - there was little to no 'changes over time'.

Comment: There's a comment right below the question that states that the OP's solution currently works.  What's the problem here?

Comment: I just wondered if this is enough or should I rather edit the question.

Comment: To do what?  I don't see an answer in the question.

Comment: The OP says: `This works in normal CSS3, but fails when running from a LESS file`, which is not true. The code he's posted in question runs perfectly fine and works as desired, yet OP says it's not correct.

Comment: That's still not an answer.  You're looking for a problem that is not there.